# Compile .DLL-s under Windows to Linux (Industrial Controller)

Tags: linux, dll, compilation, cross-platform, labview

I'm not even close to be a programmer, however I understand alot about the topic. So if the question will be trivial, than sorry.
My problem is that I'm using a device (3d scanner) and developping data manipulator applications for it in NI Labview with Windows operation system. Do able to communicate with the device, I have to include two .dll-s into the VI, to acces the functions of the device. Now I want to use an NI Industrial Controller, to compute the data directly with FPGA. However the operation system of the Industrial Controller is NI Real-time Linux (which is most likely a distribution of Debian) and the deployement of the VI applications are easy - due to the NI is made for that -, but I assume that the .dll-s won't work (obviously).
So now I try to recompile everything into Linux usage. I have the SDK for the device and I can recompile the .dll-s anytime for Windows, but in the \bin\gnu is empty (in win32 and win64, I have my .dll-s which I use with my VIs).
Unfortunately the SDK is for Visual Studio (I have .sln-s) and the National Istruments provides cross-compiling tutorial and solution only for Eclipse.
Could you help me and write me a tutorial (for a not programmer person) how to do this? I never ever used Linux before and not really familiar with gcc and toolchain what are these for...
Btw, I have a makefile, what the provide for the SDK and based on the technical support, I should use that to make the "linux libraries".

Comment: Asking for someone to write a tutorial for you might be a bit much. You need to recompile the project on your linux target machine in a linux compatible library file before you can use it from LabView. I think this tutorial might help you with that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/

Comment: It sounds to me as if you would be better off asking the manufacturer of the device if they can provide a driver suitable for the NI controller, or asking NI and/or the NI community if someone else has already implemented this, or getting the details of the device's communication protocol (how does it interface?) and writing your own driver for it. If this is beyond your skills then you may have to pay someone some money for it.

Comment: Btw when I say 'write your own driver' above, I mean using LabVIEW which I assume is the language you know best. Alternatively, NI offer industrial controllers that can run Windows Embedded 7 (the IC-3120 and upwards) as well as LabVIEW code in FPGA, which might be another solution.